# Spring boot application is not running after getting error Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/jetty/server/RequestLog$Writer

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc

```
2020-08-13 17:01:23.063  INFO 9680 --- [           main] com.isurabhi.gwtjs.GwtjsApplication      : Starting GwtjsApplication on thangaraj-Aspire-4739Z with PID 9680 (/home/thangaraj/Downloads/gwtjs/gwtjs/target/classes started by thangaraj in /home/thangaraj/Downloads/gwtjs/gwtjs)
2020-08-13 17:01:23.087  INFO 9680 --- [           main] com.isurabhi.gwtjs.GwtjsApplication      : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2020-08-13 17:01:25.259  INFO 9680 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFERRED mode.
2020-08-13 17:01:25.337  INFO 9680 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 62ms. Found 0 JPA repository interfaces.
2020-08-13 17:01:26.872  WARN 9680 --- [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start web server; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'tomcatServletWebServerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/servlet/ServletWebServerFactoryConfiguration$EmbeddedTomcat.class]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jettyWebServerFactoryCustomizer' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/embedded/EmbeddedWebServerFactoryCustomizerAutoConfiguration$JettyWebServerFactoryCustomizerConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.embedded.JettyWebServerFactoryCustomizer]: Factory method 'jettyWebServerFactoryCustomizer' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/jetty/server/RequestLog$Writer
2020-08-13 17:01:26.905  INFO 9680 --- [           main] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2020-08-13 17:01:26.920 ERROR 9680 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start web server; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'tomcatServletWebServerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/servlet/ServletWebServerFactoryConfiguration$EmbeddedTomcat.class]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jettyWebServerFactoryCustomizer' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/embedded/EmbeddedWebServerFactoryCustomizerAutoConfiguration$JettyWebServerFactoryCustomizerConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.embedded.JettyWebServerFactoryCustomizer]: Factory method 'jettyWebServerFactoryCustomizer' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/jetty/server/RequestLog$Writer
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.onRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:161) ~[spring-boot-2.3.2.RELEASE.jar:2.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:545) ~[spring-context-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:143) ~[spring-boot-2.3.2.RELEASE.jar:2.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:758) [spring-boot-2.3.2.RELEASE.jar:2.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:750) [spring-boot-2.3.2.RELEASE.jar:2.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397) [spring-boot-2.3.2.RELEASE.jar:2.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315) [spring-boot-2.3.2.RELEASE.jar:2.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1237) [spring-boot-2.3.2.RELEASE.jar:2.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1226) [spring-boot-2.3.2.RELEASE.jar:2.3.2.RELEASE]
    at com.isurabhi.gwtjs.GwtjsApplication.main(GwtjsApplication.java:10) [classes/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'tomcatServletWebServerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/servlet/ServletWebServerFactoryConfiguration$EmbeddedTomcat.class]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jettyWebServerFactoryCustomizer' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/embedded/EmbeddedWebServerFactoryCustomizerAutoConfiguration$JettyWebServerFactoryCustomizerConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.embedded.JettyWebServerFactoryCustomizer]: Factory method 'jettyWebServerFactoryCustomizer' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/jetty/server/RequestLog$Writer
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:602) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:516) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:226) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:322) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:207) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.getWebServerFactory(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:212) ~[spring-boot-2.3.2.RELEASE.jar:2.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.createWebServer(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:177) ~[spring-boot-2.3.2.RELEASE.jar:2.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.onRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:158) ~[spring-boot-2.3.2.RELEASE.jar:2.3.2.RELEASE]
    ... 9 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jettyWebServerFactoryCustomizer' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/embedded/EmbeddedWebServerFactoryCustomizerAutoConfiguration$JettyWebServerFactoryCustomizerConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.embedded.JettyWebServerFactoryCustomizer]: Factory method 'jettyWebServerFactoryCustomizer' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/jetty/server/RequestLog$Writer
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:655) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:635) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1336) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1176) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:556) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:516) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:226) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:322) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeansOfType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:624) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.server.WebServerFactoryCustomizerBeanPostProcessor.getWebServerFactoryCustomizerBeans(WebServerFactoryCustomizerBeanPostProcessor.java:87) ~[spring-boot-2.3.2.RELEASE.jar:2.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.server.WebServerFactoryCustomizerBeanPostProcessor.getCustomizers(WebServerFactoryCustomizerBeanPostProcessor.java:78) ~[spring-boot-2.3.2.RELEASE.jar:2.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.server.WebServerFactoryCustomizerBeanPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(WebServerFactoryCustomizerBeanPostProcessor.java:70) ~[spring-boot-2.3.2.RELEASE.jar:2.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.server.WebServerFactoryCustomizerBeanPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(WebServerFactoryCustomizerBeanPostProcessor.java:58) ~[spring-boot-2.3.2.RELEASE.jar:2.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsBeforeInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:415) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1786) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:594) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    ... 17 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.embedded.JettyWebServerFactoryCustomizer]: Factory method 'jettyWebServerFactoryCustomizer' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/jetty/server/RequestLog$Writer
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:185) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:650) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    ... 34 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/jetty/server/RequestLog$Writer
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.embedded.EmbeddedWebServerFactoryCustomizerAutoConfiguration$JettyWebServerFactoryCustomizerConfiguration.jettyWebServerFactoryCustomizer(EmbeddedWebServerFactoryCustomizerAutoConfiguration.java:74) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.3.2.RELEASE.jar:2.3.2.RELEASE]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_252]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_252]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_252]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_252]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    ... 35 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.eclipse.jetty.server.RequestLog$Writer
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382) ~[na:1.8.0_252]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:418) ~[na:1.8.0_252]
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:352) ~[na:1.8.0_252]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:351) ~[na:1.8.0_252]
    ... 41 common frames omitted
```

Comment: Is `jetty-server` added as dependency?

Comment: yes. I tried to add the dependency for jetty-server. The error is not shown. After creating pom from Spring Initializr, it was running good. I added some dependencies manually such as Jsoup, javax.enterprise, com.google.elemental2, then exception is thrown.

Comment: So, it works after adding jetty-server dependency?

Comment: I dont want to run Jetty server, I am trying to  run tomcat server in spring boot. The problem is GWT. The gwt eclipse plugin is running the Jetty server while i run java application spring boot.

Comment: Check answers and comments at https://stackoverflow.com/q/28564438/1776132

Answer (score 1):

for me i only use Tomcat but after i migrated springboot 1.x -> 2.x and added springfox on dependencies I started to have the same error.
it was only ok on IDEA but not on external tomcat.

following up the code
on `EmbeddedWebServerFactoryCustomizerAutoConfiguration.java`
it was trying to auto configure with JettyWebServerFactoryCustomizer then as JettyWebServerFactoryCustomizer class depend on a lot of jetty package classes it threw the error.

the solution is.
i just excluded `EmbeddedWebServerFactoryCustomizerAutoConfiguration` from bean list and it worked perfectly. tomcat is now default embedded server and it doesn't try to configure with any others.

try this annotation on your Spring Boot Application.

```java
@SpringBootApplication(exclude = org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.embedded.EmbeddedWebServerFactoryCustomizerAutoConfiguration.class)
```